# graceful shutdown of spring integration flow

Tags: spring-integration

I understand from spring integration monitoring sample
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/monitoring
how control bus can be used to shutdown an integration flow. I was wondering how is

```
@integrationMBeanExporter.stopActiveComponents(false, 20000)
```

different from just shutting down application context

```
applicationContext.stop()
```

in which the flow is loaded. Will that not achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are right. From big hight they do the same with components: call `Lifecycle.stop()`.

The difference that your application continue to work in first case and you can invoke `Lifecycle.start()` again. And `IntegrationMBeanExporter` does it only for integration components.

The `applicationContext.stop()` fully **shutdown** Spring Application context - in most cases just stop entire application.

Comment: In my case I have a parent application context which starts multiple spring-integration-flow-application-contexts. So it sounds like in that case if I want to start or stop specific flows I can stop the particular application context. Another question would be since we are stopping application context that means can it be restarted and the full spring integration flow would turn back on. Or instead it will require spawning new application contexts for the ones that have been stopped (if ur trying to restart)

Comment: Would be better `context.stop()`, `context.start()` for your use-case.